# React Native Image front of other view

Tags: css, react-native

I want to write stylesheet to display a loyout like this image:

avatar:

[image: avatar]

And I write code like this:

```
<View style={styles.header}></View>
<View style={styles.meInfor}>
    <Image style={styles.avatar}
      source={require('../../images/cristiano-ronaldo.jpg')} />
</View>
```

and style:

```
header:{
        width: width,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: '#1270BA',
    },
    meInfor:{
        width: width,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        marginTop: -50,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderRadius: 100,
    }
```

I use `marginTop: - 50` to pull the avatar to top, but the result like this:

bad result:

[image: bad result]

How can i do to style this avatar like the first image?

Comment: try to use position:'absolute' in avatar

Comment: i added this property and the avatar hidden. :(

Comment: remove the margin also

Comment: still not working for me

Comment: wait let me try at my end

Comment: Have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: this the result of the code]

Try this code it run well on my case

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Image, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
  const {header, meInfor, avatar, container} = styles; 
    return (
      <View style={container}>
        <View style={header}></View>
        <View style={meInfor}></View>
        <Image style={avatar}
      source={{uri: 'http://infosahabat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Permainan-Bola-Besar.jpg'}} 
       />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this for the style

**Style**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    },
    header:{
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: '#1270BA',
    },
    meInfor:{
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        top: 0,
        height: 50,
        width: (Dimensions.get('window').width),   
    },
    avatar: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 50,
        left: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 2) - 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 100,
    }
});
```

Comment: I want `meInfor` width = `Dimensions.get('window').width`. and only avatar borderRadius curve on header, not square.

Comment: i have update my code https://repl.it/KkQ9/5 try to check is it like what you want

Answer (score 0):

Change your stylesheet like this

```
header : {
      width: width,
      height: 100,
      backgroundColor: '#1270BA'
    },
    meInfor : {
      position: 'absolute',

      width: width,

      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    avatar : {
      marginTop: 50,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      borderRadius: 100
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but not work for me. I trick by two haft images to correct the result.

Comment: Have you wrapped above two views inside a parent view ?

Comment: yeb, they wrapped by container view:
container: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
 },